# Developer Edition org now have 256MB data storage?

Tags: data-storage

Does salesforce increase data storage for dev org?

I registered a dev org and it has 256 MB data storage.

Data Storage    256.0 MB

File Storage    902.0 MB

But my previous registered dev org still has 5 MB data storage.

Comment: No, They didn't but I have noticed they provide a special edition of dev org for the trailhead. if you create a new dev org from like that trailhead provide then only you can see the limit extended to 256MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, They didn't but I have noticed they provide a special edition of dev org for the trailhead.

if you create a new dev org that trailhead provide then only you can see the limit extended to 256MB